# How to check the version of OpenSSL in Crosswalk for Android on Windows

Tags: android, openssl, unzip, chromium-embedded, crosswalk-runtime

I'm developing an app with [Android Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/).

A few days ago, alert mail arrived from google play about a security issue of OpenSSL.

The method of verifying the version of OpenSSL was written to e-mail.

> The vulnerabilities were addressed in OpenSSL versions beginning with 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za. To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep via ("$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL""). For more information about the vulnerability, please consult http://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140605.txt.

But when unzip is run on Windows, an error is occurred("strings" is an invalid command).

Crosswalk's current version is 9.38.208.10. How can I verify OpenSSL is safe?

Comment: Did you try running this command on cygwin? That's likely to work.

Comment: I tryed by Cygwin and MinGW. But a same error occurred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197777/google-play-openssl-warning-message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crosswalk is running an older version of OpenSSL.  I work at Intel (on a different team) and we are aware of the issue and raising it with the Crosswalk team.

```
OpenSSL default user interface
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

Comment: Can I patch the openssl version myself? Are the beta/canary versions running a fixed openssl?

Comment: Chromium 39 (which Crosswalk 10 is based off) switched to BoringSSL .  https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/downloads.html  You can download Crosswalk 10 beta and you will be fine.  Thanks for taking the time to report this.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the packages containing `unzip`, `strings` and `grep` installed in cygwin order for that command to work.

From the error message, looks like you're missing `strings`. Did you install the `binutils` package?

See http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=strings.exe

Comment: I have mistaken that "strings" is a parameter. The command was successful when binutils was installed. However, a version number is not found.