# Regarding your app is statically linking against a version of OpenSSL

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded my production `apk` file about one month ago.
But, now i am getting a warning on `apk` section(or Alert section) of my Google play developer console.

> Security alert
>
> Your app is statically linking against a version of OpenSSL that has
>   multiple security vulnerabilities.  You should update OpenSSL as soon
>   as possible.
>
> The vulnerabilities were addressed in OpenSSL versions beginning with
>   1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za.  To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep via ("$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL""). 
>   For more information about the vulnerability, please consult
>   http://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140605.txt.
>
> To confirm that you've upgraded correctly, upload the updated version
>   to the Developer Console and check back after five hours.
>
> Please note, while it's unclear whether these specific issues affect
>   your application,  applications with vulnerabilities that expose users
>   to risk of compromise may be considered "dangerous products" and
>   subject to removal from Google Play.

How to fix it?Please help me.
 I am scared by last line.

> "may be considered "dangerous products"   and subject to removal from
>   Google Play."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `You should update OpenSSL as soon as possible.` And you should ask _how to update OpenSSL in Android_ with more information about your development environment.

Comment: @PacoAbato   Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Comment: And i can't figure out where am I using OpenSSL.

Comment: I have no idea on this issue. Sorry.

Comment: "And i can't figure out where am I using OpenSSL" -- it would be coming from an AAR or Android library project, most likely.

Comment: Is my question not clear.I am confused.why i am getting down voting..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197777/google-play-openssl-warning-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the extension of .apk to .zip and
Use the [serch file](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_my_files.html) for windows and search for the String "openssl"
it will show you the exact version of openssl.

Answer (score 0):

According to some Google forums, here is what they suggest you do:

(1) You can determine which apps are using OpenSSL via ("$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"")
(2) Please update all statically linked versions of OpenSSL to 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, or 0.9.8za.
(3) If you are using a 3rd party library that bundles OpenSSL, please notify the 3rd party and work with them to address this.﻿

Hope this helps.