# "Security alert" - Your app is statically linking against a version of OpenSSL Google Play

Tags: android, security, openssl

As the title suggests, what I am suffering from is the warning being raised whenever I upload a new application on Google Play Store.
As Google has suggested, I run the `$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"` command and I got the following output.

```
OpenSSLDie
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers
OpenSSL_add_all_digests
UI_OpenSSL
%s(%d): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: %s
OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
OpenSSL default
OpenSSL 'dlfcn' shared library method
You need to read the OpenSSL FAQ, http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html
OpenSSL default user interface
ASN.1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Big Number part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
CONF part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
CONF_def part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
EVP part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
lhash part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
MD5 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
PEM part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RAND part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RSA part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA-256 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Stack part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
TXT_DB part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
X.509 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
OpenSSLDie
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers
OpenSSL_add_all_digests
UI_OpenSSL
%s(%d): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: %s
OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
OpenSSL default
OpenSSL 'dlfcn' shared library method
You need to read the OpenSSL FAQ, http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html
OpenSSL default user interface
ASN.1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Big Number part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
CONF part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
CONF_def part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
EVP part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
lhash part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
MD5 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
PEM part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RAND part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RSA part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA-256 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Stack part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
TXT_DB part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
X.509 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
OpenSSLDie
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers
OpenSSL_add_all_digests
UI_OpenSSL
%s(%d): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: %s
OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
OpenSSL default
OpenSSL 'dlfcn' shared library method
You need to read the OpenSSL FAQ, http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html
OpenSSL default user interface
ASN.1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Big Number part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
CONF part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
CONF_def part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
EVP part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
lhash part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
MD5 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
PEM part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RAND part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RSA part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA-256 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Stack part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
TXT_DB part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
X.509 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
OpenSSLDie
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers
OpenSSL_add_all_digests
UI_OpenSSL
%s(%d): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: %s
OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
OpenSSL default
OpenSSL 'dlfcn' shared library method
You need to read the OpenSSL FAQ, http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html
OpenSSL default user interface
ASN.1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Big Number part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
CONF part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
CONF_def part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
EVP part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
lhash part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
MD5 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
PEM part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RAND part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RSA part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA-256 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Stack part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
TXT_DB part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
X.509 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
```

But now what to do next in order to fix the Warning on Google Play Store?
Please guide me with this.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Please help us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197777/google-play-openssl-warning-message).

Comment: Yes it's duplicate because I do not find answer about "HOW TO RESOLVE" in above link.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this security alert ?

Comment: @athi09, Yes. I had used VIN Scanner library in my project. This was using the old OpenSSL version. I searched on Google and upgraded it with new version and then updated the APK. The error than gone. In your case also, you need to find if there are any third party jars/libraries that are linked to old OpenSSL version. Sorry for late reply as I came back after a long time here.

Comment: Thank you @YuDroid for your response

Answer (score 0):

> But now what to do next in order to fix the Warning on Google Play Store?

OpenSSL 0.9.8 is now at [end of life](https://www.openssl.org/about/roadmap.html). Upgrade to OpenSSL 1.0.2.

Plus, OpenSSL 0.9.8h is downlevel. It should have been at 0.9.8ze (or something in the z*N* line).

Comment: `Please update all statically linked versions of OpenSSL to 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, or 0.9.8za.` How can I achieve this in my Windows system? Is this something regarding when we create a signed APK? I am really not aware of this.Please explain briefly to resolve this.