# Google Mandatory update to latest OpenSSL

Tags: java, android, openssl, android-security

Recently I got a mail from Google asking me to update OpenSSL or else my application would be blocked. They mentioned the steps to check OpenSSl version which I did and found that my things like MD5 SHA(encryption Algo's) are using version  **1.0.1h**.

My Question is how can I update these as I'm using latest JDK already and these are part of that only. Please suggest what should I do?

```
MD4 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
MD5 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
RC2 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
RIPE-MD160 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
SHA1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
SHA-256 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
SHA-512 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
DlSHA part of OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
```

IDE: Android Studio 2.0
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0
JDK 1.8

Comment: See [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24197777) and [Update Android app to latest version of OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30122019), perhaps that helps.

Comment: Will try this. But these are part of JDK I don't think this will help.

Comment: @Sinistro - You are down level for both Android Studio and its Gradle.

Comment: I know but, this is not the reason for this issue.. is it?

Comment: @Jww I saw your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122019/update-android-app-to-latest-version-of-openssl
Will this work on windows?

Comment: @Sinistro - Go to [Grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) and install it in `%SYSTEM%` or `%SYSTEM32%` so its on path. Then, for each dev directory you have, issue `grep -IR '1.0.1' <dir>`. A dev directory is your IDE directory, source code directory, SDK directories, etc. It will tell you where OpenSSL 1.0.1h is coming from. Then, update it. You might be able to do it with Windows Search. But I find Windows Search is more trouble than its worth because it only wants to search for Pictures and Music in My Documents. Its hard to do anything useful with it.

Comment: It's probably because one of your dependencies is adding OpenSSL as a dependency, and an older version. What libraries are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Finally got the answer for this
 1. Update Android Studio to 2.1.1 i.e. latest
 2. Update build tools wrapper etc all kinds of tools.
 3. Update all your libraries in my case major issue was from this side
 4. Clean build after this and you are good to go.
 5. Check again for OpenSSL version and now you are up-to-date.
```

Answer (score 0):

Update SDK, NDK and all other third party libraries you have used in your application.