# How to update openssl for my app android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, google-play

Google play reject my app and send me this email :

> This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for
>   users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.
>
> Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that
>   were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as
>   soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

Please I need someone help to update openssl for android app to re-submit to google play.

Thanks

Comment: Also see [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24197777), [How to grep or search .jar files for OpenSSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36213149) and [How to determine which dependency causes Google Play OpenSSL warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38187257)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can Download OpenSSL from [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/)
2. Cross-compile OpenSSL for Android [Link](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android)
3. Rebuild App

Comment: hi, singh please how to update openssl for my app in windows 10 ??

Answer (score 0):

Download stable version of OpenSSL [1.0.2] from:: [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/source/) 
Cross-compile OpenSSL for [Android](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) 
Rebuild your app, linking against the cross-compiled library

**Note:** your shared object must use static linking against OpenSSL (libssl.a and libcrypto.a). You cannot link your shared object against the OpenSSL shared objects. If you link against shared objects, then Android's Zygote (the parent of all processes), will load its down-level version and your 1.0.2 version will never load.

Comment: hi, singh please how to update openssl for my app in windows 10 ??

Comment: You should have cited the question and answer you lifted that from: [Update Android app to latest version of OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30122019/608639).