# APK Openssl version

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, google-play

I'm confused. I've receintly created Google Play app but some hours later I've recieved mesage in console that I'm using wrong OpenSSL version:

> $ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"

gives

> OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013.

But Google Play supports only 1.0.1h and latest.
I'm really do not understand how can I update OpenSSL version? SDK? NDK? Eclipse? etc... I've already downloaded the newest version. How can I fix it?

Comment: [Check it out][1] There was already a question on stackoverflow.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197777/google-play-openssl-warning-message

Comment: If OpenSSL is in your APK file, either you put it there, or some third-party library that you are using put it there. You need to determine where it is coming from in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to comments of my question. The solutions was not in libraries but in executable that added in res/raw/executablefile which included this OpenSSL.
I had to recompile this executable to fix this alert.

Comment: I keep getting `-bash: strings: command not found` when I try to run this... Any suggestions?

Comment: what did you type before receiving this message?

Comment: When I was in the directory of my apk I typed: `unzip -p android-debug.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"`. I also tried to add the location path in as part of  "android-debug.apk" before I did this I made sure both **_unzip_** and **_grep_** were installed.

Comment: @Tim `sudo apt-get install strings`

Comment: I am on a pc using Cygwin64. When I try this it returns `-bash: sudo: command not found`

Comment: try to find something like `C:\cygwin\bin\strings.exe`