# App Rejection because OpenSSL

Tags: android, openssl, google-play, intel-media-sdk

First of all this question already asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536314/openssl-app-rejection-issue-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260781/apk-openssl-version)

And I have used this command `$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"`
to get OpenSSL version, and I got

> OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011.

I'm using many libraries in app 
**this is my gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':taskspottingsdk')
    compile project(':uil_library')
    compile project(':viewPagerIndicatorLib')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.+'
    compile project(':audio_recorder')
    compile project(':material_dialogs_library')
    compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.1'
    compile project(':better_pickers_library')
    compile project(':zxscanlib')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile project(':wScratchViewLibrary')
    compile project(':drag-sort-listview')
    compile project(':mobihelp_sdk_android_v1.4')
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/android-1.2.2675.jar')
    compile files('libs/audible-magic-plugin-1.2.2675.jar')
    compile files('libs/domain-1.2.2675.jar')
    compile files('libs/wms-transport-wowz.jar')
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
}
```

So is any fast and easy way to figure out which library is using OpenSSL.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APK Openssl version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260781/apk-openssl-version)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Intel Media SDK for Mobile , they using OpenSSL 1.0.0e 
and this version has many vulnerabilities

[Look here](https://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html)