# How to check OpenSSL library version of android application

Tags: android, windows, openssl

This is related to [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24197777/608639). Play store recommend to use the following command to grep:

```
$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"
```

But on Windows, this command is not running. However I have installed WinZip, WinRAR, Cygwin and MinGW. So please help me to run this command so I can come to know the issue where it is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue which I was facing i.e. was unable to run the command

$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"

I installed Unzip Package in Cygwin by opening the setup of Cygwin and then It shows all the packages available for Cygwin, selected Unzip package and updated. After that above mentioned command work like charm in Cygwin terminal.

Comment: @NiravRanpara install `strings` in your SO or Cygwin