# Google Play security alert due to ActionScript and OpenSSL

Tags: android, actionscript-3, openssl, flash-cs5, developer-tools

I am a beginner app developer using Adobe Flash and ActionScript 3. Recently I got this Security Alert about OpenSSL. I have no idea what is it about, they give me until the 7th of July to fix it otherwise they will block publishing any new apps.

Please help me and I'll be so grateful.

Here is the alert:

> ***Security alert*** We wanted to let you know that your application is statically linking against a version of OpenSSL that has multiple
>   security vulnerabilities for users. Please migrate your app to an
>   updated version of OpenSSL by Jul 7, 2015. Starting on this date,
>   Google Play will block publishing of any new apps and updates that use
>   older, unsupported versions of OpenSSL (see below for details).
>
> REASON FOR WARNING: Violation of the dangerous products provision of
>   the Content Policy and sections 4.4 of the Developer Distribution
>   Agreement. The vulnerabilities were fixed in OpenSSL versions
>   beginning with 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za. To confirm your OpenSSL
>   version, you can do a grep via:
>
> ```
> $ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"
> ```
>
> For more information about the vulnerability, please see this OpenSSL
>   Security Advisory. To confirm that you've upgraded correctly, upload
>   the updated version of the app to the Developer Console and check back
>   after five hours. For other technical questions about managing
>   OpenSSL, please see
>   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mailing.openssl.users.
>
> On Jul 7, 2015, we will not accept app updates containing the
>   vulnerabilities. In addition, we will reject new apps containing the
>   vulnerabilities. Note: while the issues may not affect every app that
>   uses OpenSSL versions prior to 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, or 0.9.8za, developers
>   should stay up to date on all security patches. Even if you think that
>   specific issues may not be relevant, it's good practice to update any
>   libraries in your app that have known issues. Please take this time to
>   update apps that have out-of-date dependent libraries or other
>   vulnerabilities.
>
> Before publishing applications, please ensure your apps' compliance
>   with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Content Policy. If you
>   feel we have sent this warning in error, visit this Google Play Help
>   Center article.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197777/google-play-and-openssl-warning-message)

Answer (score 2):

> please help me and i'll be so grateful for that

Update the SDKs, libraries and frameworks you are using. Stop treating them like an outdated Maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

Open java run-time environment.
2. You config your java checkbox.
3. Enable ssl services latest version.
4. Upgrade your Adobe Air.
5. Check memory box JRE.
6. Try again and publish apk version "1.1.0"

That must work...
GL