# Cocos2dx, Google Play warning and vulnerable version of OpenSSL March 2016 New Warning

Tags: android, curl, openssl, google-play, cocos2d-x

We have been developing game Cocos2DX and we received the warning from google witch states that

> Your app(s) listed at the end of this email utilize a version of OpenSSL that contains one or more security vulnerabilities.Please migrate your app(s) to OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r or higher as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK. Beginning July 11, 2016, Google Play will block publishing of any new apps or updates that use older versions of OpenSSL. If you’re using a 3rd party library that bundles OpenSSL, you’ll need to upgrade it to a version that bundles OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r or higher.
>   The vulnerabilities were addressed in OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r. The latest versions of OpenSSL can be downloaded here. To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep search for ($ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL").

This happened last year also and we fixed it but we have no solution for this for now as cocos2DX has to update their SDK.
Does any one has any solution to this? Or can confirm if Cocos2D has this issue or some other 3rd party SDK.

Comment: Which Cocos2dx version are you using? I'm using Cocos2dx v3.8.1 and I received this warning from Google too.

Comment: Just try and get the latest version of OpenSSL directly from them.https://www.openssl.org

Comment: But how can I add openssl in Cocos2DX ? is there any way? It seems the libCurl library needs to be updated and coco2dX havent provided that with the required open ssl version

Comment: got the same  issues today in mail from google

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197777/google-play-and-openssl-warning-message).

Comment: No its not a duplicate. That issue was raised in 2015 and open ssl was updated to 1.0.1h now it is another issue but with open ssl as well and it seems till now cocos2dx has not fixed it yet.

Comment: @JawadAmjad - And from the accepted answer below... You have to update the SDK to get the latest tools. How is this not an exact duplicate? Switch vendors if they can't keep up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update libcurl.

Check this thread to see which version you need:

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/openssl-problem-again/28270/56

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. While this answer can actually help the OP with a solution, could you quote the contents of your link relevant to this question? This would help further visitors, should the link ever go AWOL.