# Android Vitamio 5.0.0 and vulnerable version of OpenSSL

Tags: android, openssl, vitamio

I am using Vitamio 5.0.0 version for my app in Google Play. Today i gat a mail from google. it says "Google Play warning: You are using a vulnerable version of OpenSSL "

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> Your app(s) listed at the end of this email utilize a version of
>   OpenSSL that contains one or more security vulnerabilities. If you
>   have more than 20 affected apps in your account, please check the
>   Developer Console for a full list.
>
> Please migrate your app(s) to OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r or higher as soon as
>   possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.
>   Beginning July 11, 2016, Google Play will block publishing of any new
>   apps or updates that use older versions of OpenSSL. If you’re using a
>   3rd party library that bundles OpenSSL, you’ll need to upgrade it to a
>   version that bundles OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r or higher.
>
> The vulnerabilities were addressed in OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r. The latest
>   versions of OpenSSL can be downloaded here. To confirm your OpenSSL
>   version, you can do a grep search for ($ unzip -p YourApp.apk |
>   strings | grep "OpenSSL").
>
> To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version to
>   the Developer Console and check back after five hours. If the app
>   hasn’t been correctly upgraded, we will display a warning.
>
> The vulnerabilities include "logjam" and CVE-2015-3194. The Logjam
>   attack allows a man-in-the-middle attacker to downgrade vulnerable TLS
>   connections to 512-bit export-grade cryptography. This allows the
>   attacker to read and modify any data passed over the connection.
>   Details about other vulnerabilities are available here. For other
>   technical questions, you can post to Stack Overflow and use the tags
>   “android-security” and “OpenSSL.”
>
> While these specific issues may not affect every app that uses
>   OpenSSL, it’s best to stay up to date on all security patches. Apps
>   with vulnerabilities that expose users to risk of compromise may be
>   considered in violation of our Malicious Behavior policy and section
>   4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.
>
> Apps must also comply with the Developer Distribution Agreement and
>   Developer Program Policies. If you feel we have sent this warning in
>   error, contact our policy support team through the Google Play
>   Developer Help Center.
>
> Regards,
>
> The Google Play Team

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Question is "What can we do at this case" I appeal to the Vitamio authorities here... in Vitamio 5.0.0 has a Open SSL problem. Google says that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197777/google-play-and-openssl-warning-message). If you want to appeal to Vitamio, then you need to contact them directly. Their website is at [http://www.vitamio.org](https://www.vitamio.org). Stack Overflow and Vitamio are not affiliated, as far as I know.

Comment: No duplicate  they are not same. İ send mail to vitamio directly but i dont have any response and i want to search another solution!

Comment: let me know if you find any solution : )

Comment: okay @SalmanAshraf if i found solution i will write here :)

Comment: @Kadri please share solution

Comment: yes @Florida if you found. I will share sloution...