# How to update openssl version in android?

Tags: openssl, google-play, instagram-api, android-security

I want to fix apps with OpenSSL cve-2014-0224 and other vulnerabilities in my android app. I am using `WebView` for integration with [Instagram SDK](http://www.instagram.com/developer/).

Comment: Is this a Google Play warning?

Comment: Yes. This is google Play warning.

Comment: There's already a question on the subject and answers at [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197777/google-play-and-openssl-warning-message). You need to update the NDK, your IDE and the Instagram SDK. If you have a problem that's not answered in the duplicate, then please click *Edit* in the lower left corner and add the additional details. I can remove the duplicate in this case.