# Google Play and OpenSSL vulnerability warning

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, google-play, boringssl

When I submit new APK to Google Play, my APK is rejected with message:

```
Vulnerability   APK Version(s)
OpenSSL
The vulnerabilities were fixed in OpenSSL versions beginning with 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za.
To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep via:

$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"
```

I checked my APK, and it using 1.0.1c version of OpenSSL. But from Android 6.0, [Google recommends using BoringSSL instead of OpenSSL](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html).

What should I do now?

Comment: *"I checked my APK, and it using 1.0.1c version of OpenSSL..."* - why are you using 1.0.1c?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24197777).

Answer (score 1):

According to [link](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6376725?hl=en), it is enough to update OpenSSL version to the latest. Also, you can use BoringSSL if you want, [here](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/HEAD/BUILDING.md) and [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html) are useful links.