# Defective OpenSSL version - Android

Tags: android, openssl, prelaunch

Our last Google play pre-launch report has a defective openSSL version stability issue. The application doesn't use openSSL directly, so it should be using in one of the third party libraries. How to find which third party library is using this defective version of openSSL?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197777/google-play-and-openssl-warning-message

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using any **OpenSSL library Upgrade it** to latest.

Or if you are using any library like **Agora** etc. Upgrade it to latest.

If latest library of that doesn't `compatible` then don't use that library or contact that **library forums**